# Infinite login loop in Debian Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, login

I am trying to write a small character device kernel module and somehow, I managed to fill up my virtual hard drive by reading from it (??).
Now as soon as I type in my password at the gui prompt, the screen goes back to black and drops me right where I started, again the prompt. I can drop into a shell and log in, but I can't do a lot, since every auto-completion attempt is met with a `not enough space` message, which is a pain.
I increased the size of the virtual drive with `VBoxManage`, but strangely, nothing changes.

How can I get Debian back to log in via Gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I simply needed to free up some space.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have increased the size of your virtual hard disk, but not the partition. That's why you're still out of space.

GUI cannot start, because starting requires some files to be created on disk.

The most convenient way to fix this would probably be to boot a GUI-based Linux off an ISO image and free up the disk space using some file manager.